# Create array of dictionaries in objective c

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I am fetching dictionaries from my local database.
My database array with name **aryTitle_DB** structure is as mentioned below.

> (    {
>           "date":13/9/2014;
>   "title"="abc"
>   },    {  "date":13/9/2014;
>   "title"="def"  },    {  "date":13/9/2014;
>   "title"="ghi"  },    {"date":14/9/2014;
>   "title"="abc"    },    { "date":15/9/2014;
>   "title"="abc"   },     { "date":15/9/2014;
>   "title"="def"   })

I need following type of array structure from **aryTitle_DB**

> (    { "13/9/2014":("abc","def","ghi")   },    {  "14/9/2014":("abc")  },    { "15/9/2014":("abc","def")   } )

I did lot of search in stack overflow and in other tutorials but unable to find it.
please help to create such kind of array structure.
Help will be appreciable.

Comment: Your target structure is kind of silly.  You should have a dictionary keyed by date, with the entries being arrays of titles  (If you want the above structure you will have to go through this structure anyway, as an intermediate step.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSMutableArray *fromDB;
NSMutableArray *filtered;
filtered = [NSMutableArray new];
while (fromDB.count > 0){
    NSDictionary *uniqueDate;
    NSArray *filteredDate;
    NSMutableArray *newDate;
    uniqueDate = fromDB[0];
    filteredDate = [fromDB filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.date=%K",uniqueDate[@"date"]]];
    [fromDB removeObjectsInArray:filteredDate];
    newDate = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (NSDictionary *oneDate in filteredDate) {
        [newDate addObject:oneDate[@"title"]];
    }
    uniqueDate = @{uniqueDate[@"date"]:newDate};
    [filtered addObject:uniqueDate];
};
```

this code should work. may be format of predicate should be changed, because i didn't test it. instead of format you can use formated string with filled var field.

Answer (score 0):

In objective-C, there is no generics, this has only arrived with Swing in fact.
So your data structure is only a classical a `NSArray` of `NSDictionary`.

If you want to declare this `( { "13/9/2014":("abc","def","ghi") }, { "14/9/2014":("abc") }, { "15/9/2014":("abc","def") } )` in objC you ay do it like that

```
NSMutableArray* result = [NSMutableArray new];
NSDictionary * dict = [NSDictionary new];
// With Modern objective C syntax, it would be like that :
dict["13/9/2014"] = @{"abc","def","ghi"};
dict["14/9/2014"] = @{"abc"};
dict["15/9/2014"] = @{"abc","def"};

[result addObject:dict];
```

But of course you can create intermediate `NSMutableArray` for each values and use `setValue:ForKey:` method of `NSDictionary` to add it to dictionary.

Edit : added algorithm to parse DB answer

```
NSArray*DBAnswer; // this is your array containing the answer from the DB
NSDictionary*result=[NSDictionary new];
for(NSDictionary*d in DBAnswer)
{
    NSMutableArray*list;
    if(![result containsKey:d["date"]])
    {
       list = [NSMutableArray new];
       result[d["date"]] = list;
    } 
    else 
    { 
       list = result[d["date"]];
    }
    [list addObject:d["title"]];
}

// After that you have the structure in the result NSDictionary
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply but the thing is I am fetching dictionary objects from DB which gives me above array. I need to create array which I have mentioned in my question from fetching db array.